# how to calculate the GPU required to run CNN

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I developed a convlutional neural network using Keras train and test it perfectly, now I need to know how much of GPU usage dose it takes to run the prediction of the network

the network architecture is below anlong side the the number of paramerters :

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 16, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 8, 8, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 4096)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 240)               983280    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 24)                5784      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,007,880
Trainable params: 1,007,880
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

and if there is away to calculate it for deep neural network DNN

Comment: What exactly do you want to compute? GPU usage is abstract, concrete measures can be time, FLOPS, etc

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro basicly, how many prediction per second

Comment: and how much dose it take from the gpu usage cause i have 3 more models need to be run at the same time